# Is it possible to pre-pend each STDERR with a given string

Tags: python, linux, stdout, stderr, pexpect

I am writing a program to interact with a linux machine through the serial port, and I am using pexpect.spawn as my main communication channel as follows:

```
proc = pexpect.spawn("cu dir -l /dev/ttyUSB0 -s 115200", logfile = *someFile*)
```

and I am sending commands to the machine with the sendline("cmd") method, and at the end of each session I parse the log file to see how the commands behaved.

I would like to be able to distinguish between lines that were printed to stdout and stderr from my log file, but currently I have no way of doing that.
Is that a way to globally prepend each line printed to stderr with a given string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't mention how you capture stdout and stderr, but one simple way distinguish the stdout and stderr is to simply place stdout and stderr in different files. For example:

./command.py >stdout-log 2>stderr-log

Comment: I 'capture' them through the logfile that pexpect.spawn provides. Since the commands are running on a different computer, I can not save them to a file (because I can not transfer files between the two machines)

Comment: Wait, are you trying to capture stdout/stderr from the instance of cu or from the commands run on the remote linux machine?

Comment: From the commands running on the remote linux machine, sorry if that was not clear in my question

Comment: Then the use of pexpect/etc is not at all relevant -- there is no way on the local machine to distinguish one kind of output on the remote machine from another, and the only thing that matters is the code running on the remote machine.

Comment: Yes, and my question is whether there is a way to configure the remote  machine to prepend something, say [ERR], to each line printed to stderr

Comment: If you can alter the code on the remote machine, you could. However, it feels like you are not describing the actual problem you are trying to solve here. Can you expand?

Comment: Ok, for the sake of simplicity, ignore the fact that I am running commands on a remote machine. On any linux machine, is there a way of prepending text to any arbitrary line printed to stderr. Eg, doing rm imaginaryFile would produce "rm: cannot remove `imaginaryFile': No such file or directory" ... but I want it to produce "[this is STDERR] rm: cannot remove `imaginaryFile': No such file or directory"

Comment: You can't do this for absolutely every command you run automatically by executing some magic command. However, you could run every command individually with its stderr redirected to a program that prepended a message. You could even use awk or sed to do that -- you need not write a custom program. You could also run whole shell scripts through such a filter.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a limitation of pexpect.  You're basically dealing with a black box command prompt, so pexpect has no knowledge about whether a string returned to the console (effectively) is stdout or stderr, just that something came back.  Can you safely assume a limited set of message and error formats in your system so that you could write some regex-based post-processor?

Comment: Unfortunately not, the system has to work with an arbitrary set of commands